# Number of terms in $\left(\sum_{k=0}^{10} x^{4k}\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^{8} x^{5j}\right)$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> Find the number of terms in $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{10} x^{4k}\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^{8} x^{5j}\right)$$

Since $k = \overline{0,10}$ and $j = \overline{0,8}$ we have $11\cdot 9 = 99$ distinct powers of $x$ in the product and hence $99$ terms. Is this correct argument?

Program yields $69$ terms if I'm not mistaken.

```
69
{0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 
55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 
67, 68, 70, 71, 72, 75, 76, 80}
```

Comment: When you multiply the monomials corresponding to the pairs $(k=0,j=4)$ and $(k=5,j=0)$ you get $x^{20}$ twice...so in 99 possibilities you are overcounting

Comment: @Giulio So I need to subtract $3$ since $x^{20},x^{40},x^{60}$ are counted twice ($(0,20), (20,0), (0,40),(40,0),(20,40),(40,20)$)

Comment: the monomials $x^m$ which have a coefficient greater than $1$ are those for which you can write $m=4k+5j$ in two different ways (while $j,k$ being in the ranges given in your problem); your examples ($m=20,40,60$) are fine indeed, but not all of them.
For example $24=4\cdot 1+5\cdot 1=4\cdot 6+5\cdot 0$

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that the powers range between 0 and 80, so by a simple check, the answer of 99 terms does not make sense. This is because like terms combine and coefficients are added, so there are less terms in the final product once all arithmetic is done.

Now, it's time to see which coefficients between 0 and 80 can actually be formed. Exponents are valid if they can be written as $4a+5b$ for $0\leq a \leq 10$ and $0 \leq b \leq 8$. By a corollary of the [Chicken McNugget Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem), there are $(4-1)(5-1)/2$ = 6 exponents that cannot be formed because they are too small. By symmetry, there are also 6 exponents that cannot be formed because they are too large (either we ran out of multiples  of 4, or we ran out of multiples of 5). To see this symmetry, replace $a$ by $10-a$ and $b$ by $8-b$.

So, in total, there are 12 exponents that cannot be formed. Subtracting this from the 81 possible exponents between 0 and 80 yields the final answer of 69.